# Time needed to decrypt a message $r=p\times q$, where $r$ is the message.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

If we can represent a secret message by a large prime
number $p$, we can transmit over the network the number $r = p · q$, where $ q > p$
is another large prime number that acts as the encryption key and $r$ can take 100 bits.

**Question**: What is the worst-case time complexity of the above algorithm?

Since the input to the algorithm is just one large number $r$, assume that the input size $n$ is the number of bytes needed to store $r$, that is, $n = \frac{\log_2{n}}{8}$, and that each division takes time $O(n)$. So we need $\frac{r}{p}$ divisions in order to get the encrypted message. Now the questions is how we can calculate the complexity of the algorithm where we need to guess each and every single possibility, thus I said we need $\frac{r}{p}$ divisions.

$$\frac{r}{p} = \frac{r}{2^{100}} ~~divisions$$

**Problem**: I assume the complexity in the question is referring to number of divisions or both divisions and space? So, the question is now, I am not sure why the complexity is $O(n \times 2^{4n})$?

Comment: Side comment: as an encryption scheme this doesn’t quite make sense.  If you already have a shared secret key that’s as large as the message, then just use it as a one-time pad :).  I guess it could be a feature that the message can be recovered with effort if the key is lost.

Comment: There is a detailed answer to your question on Wikipedia: [Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

Comment: @Pin. Thank you. Pin, I am asking about complexity please not the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing each and every probability is not exactly an algorithm, since it doesn’t specify what order we’re guessing in.  Nevertheless, the most reasonable interpretation is that we’re using trial division to find $p$, not $q$ which is the larger divisor of $r$.  The lengt of $p$ is at most half the number of bits of $r$, which is $4n$.  So $2^{4n}$ is the order of the maximum value of $p$.

Comment: Thank you! Got it. So again, if length of $p$ is at most half since $q>p$, then $p < \frac{\frac{log_2{n}}{8}}{2} = \frac{log_2{n}}{16} \frac{log_2{n}}{2^4}$. So I am not sure how you get $2^{4n}$ please?

Comment: @Avra $r$ has $n$ bytes, thus $8n$ bits.  Half of that is $4n$ so $p$ has up to $4n$ bits.  A number that’s $4n$ bits long is proportional to $2^{4n}$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. So since we have $2^{4n}$ possibilities and each take $n$ time to divide, so we have a total of $O(n\times 2^{4n})$?

Comment: @Avra Correct, assuming division can be done in $O(n)$ time as mentioned in the question.  I think this is a tiny bit smaller than the true cost, but it is true for very small divisors, and not that far from the truth.